# all roots of $f(z) = z^n + z^3 + z + 2$ tend to the unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose that $f (z) = z^n + z^3 + z + 2.$

Show that all roots of  $f$ tend to the
unit circle as $n \to \infty$.

I have no idea how to solve this problem...

Comment: This equation can be written as product of $(z-p_n)$ where $z_n$ is the n'th zero. Then it's easy to see that product of all zeroes must equal 2, all the combinations which give us $z$ sum up to 1, same for $z^3$ and $z^n$. Rest of the terms sum up to $0$. This results in n equations. Hope this helps.

Comment: You could try using Rouche's theorem.

Comment: I'm with Lord shark on this one. Rouche's theorem will provide you with the conditions to compare this polynomial to the one you would typically associate with elements of the unit circle.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exits $N>0$, such that if $n>N$, then for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $||z|-1|>\varepsilon$, $z^n+z^3+z+2\neq 0$.

If $|z|-1>\varepsilon$,  $|z^n+z^3+z+2|\geq|z|^n-|z|^3-|z|-2\geq (1+\varepsilon)^n-(1+\varepsilon)^3-(1+\varepsilon)-2\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus there is some $N_1$ such that if $n>N_1$, $z^n+z^3+z+2\neq 0$ for $|z|-1>\varepsilon$.

If $|z|-1<-\varepsilon$, then $|z^n+z^3+z+2|\geq 2-|z|^n-|z|^3-|z|\geq 2-(1-\varepsilon)^n-(1-\varepsilon)^3-(1-\varepsilon)\to 
2-(1-\varepsilon)^3 - (1-\varepsilon)>0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus there is some $N_2$ such that if $n>N_2$, $z^n+z^3+z+2\neq 0$ for $|z|-1<-\varepsilon$.

In conclusion, for $n>\max(N_1,N_2)$, $z^n+z^3+z+2\neq 0$ for $||z|-1|>\varepsilon$. Thus all roots of $z^n+z^3+z+2$ tend to the circle as $n\to\infty$.